# Error in SQL loader, number not valid ORA-01722

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I want to charge a sql loader in field named `ID_CARGA`, this one is a `number(18)` in database.

I have in loader this line:

```
ID_CARGA(1:18) ":ID_CARGA",
```

But when i try to load this data:

```
000000000000000000
```

Says that `ORA-01722`, How can i load this values as a valid numbers?

```
000000000000000000 like  0
000000000000000001 like 1
000000000000000150 like 150
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ID_CARGA position(1:18)  NUMBER "TO_NUMBER(:ID_CARGA)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have the `":ID_CARGA"` in your control file like this:

```
ID_CARGA(1:18) ":ID_CARGA",
```

Specifically with a control file which describes a fixed
format data, all you need to do is this:

```
ID_CARGA position(1:18),
```

Typically, you would have a quoted section of your data description for the
ID_CARGA column if you were to invoke a SQL function.  In your particular
case, no SQL function is being called, thus it is unecessary.

When I run this modified form, my data loads fine.

Here is my variation of your example:

```
CREATE TABLE "SCOTT"."TEST" 
   (    "ID_CARGA" NUMBER(18,0)
   );
```

Control file:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=0)
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
BADFILE 'test_bad.bad'
DISCARDFILE 'test_dis.dsc'
APPEND
INTO TABLE SCOTT.TEST 
(
ID_CARGA position(1:18)
)
BEGINDATA
000000000000000000
000000000000000001
000000000000000150

SCOTT@dev> 
SCOTT@dev> CREATE TABLE scott.test
  2    ( id_carga NUMBER(18,0)
  3    );

Table created.

SCOTT@dev> commit;

Commit complete.

SCOTT@dev> SELECT * FROM scott.test
  2  ;

  ID_CARGA
==========
         0
         1
       150
```